# Install Mono in RedHat

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, installation, .net, libraries

I installed successfully [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) in my ubuntu 11, and now I have to do it in Redhat.

The problem is I don't have access to this machine (and haven't done it before). And the one who is going to do it asked me what are the library wich have to be installed.

In the official website there is no doc for Redhat, but google have. But the problem is that I don't have access to test it.

Can anyone tell me how to do it, or what are the libraries to install.

Answer (score 0):

There are notes available (some outdated) when Googling for "install mono redhat", but the fact is that it's not straightforward. Red Hat simply isn't a platform the mono devs want to support directly.

Your best bet is to grab VirtualBox and install Red Hat (a version that matches your target system) and document your efforts in getting it installed, then send that to the people that are working on it. It'll take time, but by working on a system that matches (or nearly matches) your target system you'll have a process that *should* work in your circumstances. Depending on the reason for the install, you could also just ship them the VM to use. If you want to consider that alternative (shipping an appliance for use) I'd suggest using VMWare for the creation of the VM.